# Can I query for a list of available chatter groups?

Tags: apex, soql, chatter-groups

I need to display in a select list the available chatter groups to select from, is this possible without hard coding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can query the CollaborationGroup Object. For example the following query

```
SELECT Id,Name From CollaborationGroup WHERE CollaborationType='Public'
```

will return all the Public chatter groups

for more details check this http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroup.htm